# Angular bind object element to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I got the code from another question and it's straightforward and working fine

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<p ng-bind-html="testHTML"></p>
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.testHTML = 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
                         '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Suppose, I'm getting an object and I want to show an element of the object

```
var obj = {
   title: 'Title',
   description: 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
       '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>'
};
$scope.testHTML = obj;
```

Then how should I bind only the description on the html end?
I've tried 
`<p ng-bind-html="{{testHTML.description}}"></p>`and 
`<p ng-bind-html="testHTML.description"></p>`

[plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/i1oqPEbwa0qM38NYpCom?p=preview)

Comment: Did you assign $scope.testHTML = obj, then var obj = {...} in your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet to bind HTML

Firstly, you can create custom filter to bind the HTML in AngularJS.

Now, you can use this filter anywhere into the myApp module by just writing `yourHTML | html`, That will done the job.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
  var obj = {
     title: 'Title',
     description: 'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
       '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>',
     description1: 'I am an <b>HTML</b>string with ' +
       '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <u><b>stuff</b></u>'
    
  };
  $scope.testHTML = obj;
  
  //Use $SCE in controller
  var preview_data = obj.description;
  $scope.htmlSafe = $sce.trustAsHtml(preview_data);
  
}]);
//Custom filter (Alternate way)
myApp.filter('html', ['$sce', function ($sce) { 
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };    
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="GreetingController">
  
  <b>By using custom filter</b>
  <div ng-bind-html="testHTML.description | html"></div>
  <div ng-bind-html="testHTML.description1 | html"></div>

  <br/>
  <b>By using $SCE inside controller</b>
  <div ng-bind-html="htmlSafe"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Console's saying $sce.trustAsHTML is not a function

Comment: I've created the snippet that is working, if you can check that.
or provide me your jsfiddle.

Comment: Which version of Angular Js you're using ? it should be 1.2 at least

Comment: @SagnikChakraborti I've updated my answer and added two ways to do this.

Comment: Thank You. It's working fine now. Had a problem in my code. However, with `ngSanitize` iframe wasn't showing. I don't know why but I'm curious. Now it's showing perfectly. :)

Comment: @SagnikChakraborti Glad to see that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

in plnkr example of html file:

change `<p ng-bind-html="{{testHtml.desc}}"></p>`to `<p ng-bind-html="testHtml.desc"></p>` as below:

```
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html=testHtml.desc></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bind-html` doesn't require interpolation as it accepts an expression, so you only need to set it to `testHtml.desc` without the curly braces `{{}}`.

In your plunkr's controller you're assigning `obj` to `$scope.testHtml` before you declare `obj` itself, so it won't render anything since `obj` is undefined at assignment.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/GvujCcYdCqLvwwnuEnWp?p=preview