# Angular.js How to render a HTML tag from json file

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to parse html value in my angular page, not sure what I am doing wrong, I am getting this error in my console:

> app.js:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

**app.js**

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('app/test.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.projects = res.data;
        });

       App.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
});
```

**test.json**

```
[
  { "icon": "<i class="fa fa-github fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>", "name": "lovelycss" },
  { "icon": "<i class="fa fa-github fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>", "name": "lovely-icons" }
]
```

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="project in projects">
     <div ng-bind-html="'{{project.icon}}' | to_trusted"></div>- <em>{{project.name}}</em>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

what I am trying to archive is this: http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1547/

I want  a json loading the icons and the text.

I hope now this will be clear.

Comment: Try my this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39384192/6608101

Comment: which line is 13 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `}` in your controller declaration and a `[` in your filter declaration:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('app/test.json')
         .then(function(res){
            $scope.projects = res.data;
          });
}); // You are missing a '}' here

App.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]); // You are missing a ']' here
```

You will also have to edit your JSON to escape your quotes `"`

```
[
    {
        "icon": "<i class=\"fa fa-github fa-3x\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
        "name": "lovelycss"
    }, {
        "icon": "<i class=\"fa fa-github fa-3x\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>",
        "name": "lovely-icons"
    }
]
```

And the expression you are passing to `ng-bind-html` is also wrong. Because of the single quotes `'` you are passing a literal string `'{{project.icon}}'` to the filter. You have to remove the quotes and the curly braces, because the `ng-bind-html` directive needs an expression as a parameter.

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="project in projects">
     <div ng-bind-html="project.icon | to_trusted"></div>- <em>{{project.name}}</em>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but i am getting this error now: SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 25
    at xc (angular.js:1326)
    at dc (angular.js:10515)
    at angular.js:10606
    at r (angular.js:321)
    at hd (angular.js:10605)
    at c (angular.js:11403)
    at angular.js:16170
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17444)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17257)
    at m.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:1364)

Comment: @Raduken That's because you have to scape the quotes (") with a backslash this way: \" I will edit my answer to add that.

Comment: thanks but in my html is loading this: {{project.icon}} , to be fair I want a Icon there rendered, understand? I don't want show the <i> tag but the icon, understand?

Comment: @Raduken I understand. Please, edit your question providing all the information, with all the steps you have gone through. I will edit my answer to provide a solution for that problem as well.

Comment: @Raduken Answer editted. I hope this is the final solution :)

Answer (score 3):

The message tells you the problem: you have a syntax error. Two actually.

1. the function for your controller is not closed.
2. there is not closing bracket for the filter.

**app.js**

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('app/test.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.projects = res.data;
        });
}); // 1

App.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]); // 2
```

For JSON ERROR fix using this

```
[
  { "icon": "<i class='fa fa-github fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "name": "lovelycss" },
  { "icon": "<i class='fa fa-github fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "name": "lovely-icons" }
]
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting this error now: SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 25
    at xc (angular.js:1326)
    at dc (angular.js:10515)
    at angular.js:10606
    at r (angular.js:321)
    at hd (angular.js:10605)
    at c (angular.js:11403)
    at angular.js:16170
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17444)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17257)
    at m.scopePrototype.$digest (hint.js:1364)

Comment: You have used double quotes inside the string content in the json (which is not allowed since we're already using double quotes for strings) ; see the edit

Comment: thanks but in my html is loading this: {{project.icon}} , to be fair I want a Icon there rendered, understand? I don't want show the <i> tag but the icon, understand?